# Understanding the change of coordinates in differential operators

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading the book "A Course on Partial Differentail Equations" by Walter Craig, and in the section 2.4 of the book the author claims the following:

"... sometimes called the Cauchy problem:
$$
\partial_t^2 u - \partial_x ^2 u = 0, \\
u(0,x) = f(x), \quad \partial_t u(0,x) = g(x).
$$
The initial data comprises two functions $f$ and $g$ that are to be specified. Introduce the new coordinates
$$
x + t:=r, \quad x-t =s,
$$
so that the differential operators are transformed as follows:
$$
\partial_t - \partial_x = 2\partial_r, \quad \partial_t + \partial_x = -2\partial_s."
$$
It's this change of coordinates that is not clear to me... I mean, why is that last sentence true? I'm guessing it's just something silly, but after thinking a bit, it was still not clear to me how to get this.

Comment: You're really just letting $u(x,t)\to u(r(x,t),s(x,t))$ so by the chain rule $u_{t}\to u_{r}r_{t}+u_{s}s_{t}=u_{r}-u_{s}$. This is just two operators acting on the function $u$ $$\partial_{t}u=(\partial_{r}-\partial_{s})u$$ so we have $\partial_{t}\equiv\partial_{r}-\partial_{s}$. Similarly, $u_{x}\to u_{r}+u_{s}$ so that $\partial_{x}\equiv\partial_{r}+\partial_{s}$. Hence, by adding and subtracting the two results for $\partial_{t},\partial_{x}$ we get $2\partial_{r}\equiv\partial_{x}+\partial_{t},2\partial_{s}\equiv\partial_{x}-\partial_{t}$. It would seem there is a typo in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that is a typo in the book or not, but here's what I remember from learning d'Alembert's formula. The solution in the original coordinate is $u(t, x)$. Introducing the new coordinates $r = x + t$ and $s = x - t$, we have $x = \dfrac{r + s}{2}$ and $t = \dfrac{r - s}{2}$ and so
$$u(t, x) = u\left(\frac{r - s}{2}, \frac{r + s}{2}\right) = v(r, s).$$
It follows from Chain Rule that
$$ \partial_tu = \partial_rv\cdot\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} + \partial_sv\cdot \frac{\partial s}{\partial t} = \partial_rv - \partial_sv. $$
Similarly, one can show that $\partial_xu = \partial_rv + \partial_sv$. In particular,
\begin{align*} 
\partial_tu + \partial_xu & = 2\partial_rv \\ 
\partial_tu - \partial_xu & = -2\partial_sv.  
\end{align*}
The wave equation transforms to
$$(\partial_t - \partial_x)(\partial_t + \partial_x)u = -4\partial_{sr}v = 0. $$